# Print this Multiplication Table

Tags: code-golf, kolmogorov-complexity

Write shortest code to print the following Multiplication Table:

```
1×1=1
1×2=2  2×2=4
1×3=3  2×3=6  3×3=9
1×4=4  2×4=8  3×4=12 4×4=16
1×5=5  2×5=10 3×5=15 4×5=20 5×5=25
1×6=6  2×6=12 3×6=18 4×6=24 5×6=30 6×6=36
1×7=7  2×7=14 3×7=21 4×7=28 5×7=35 6×7=42 7×7=49
1×8=8  2×8=16 3×8=24 4×8=32 5×8=40 6×8=48 7×8=56 8×8=64
1×9=9  2×9=18 3×9=27 4×9=36 5×9=45 6×9=54 7×9=63 8×9=72 9×9=81
```

Comment: Is anyone really going to do anything besides 2 `for` loops? Where's the challenging (interesting) part?

Comment: I don't use `for`. Ok, I use  `while`.

Comment: Are trailing spaces important?

Comment: why in the first column there are 2 spaces and not 1? (as the other colums )

Comment: @jdstankosky My answer uses the inverted upper triangle of a scaled identity matrix :).

Comment: @jdstankosky perhaps you may find my answer a bit more interesting - no loops involved

Comment: Are we even allowed to use *x* in place of *×*? (If not, that invalidates a whole lot of programs)

Comment: @jdstankosky I use a `time` loop!

Answer (score 14):

### Excel, <s>92</s> 91 Bytes

From the VBA editor's immediate window, run the following command:
`Range("A1:I9").Formula="=IF(ROW()<COLUMN(),"""",COLUMN()&""×""&ROW()&""=""&COLUMN()*ROW())"`
The output is directly on the active worksheet.
[image: Excel output screenshot]

I golfed an extra byte by swapping the order of an `if` to change `>=` to `<`.  I didn't update the screenshot, but it only affects the formula at the top, not the output.

Comment: HA! I wondered when I'd see an excel answer, +1.

Comment: Thanks.  I think I was partially motivated by the comments about doing it without the usual nested `FOR` loop.

Comment: Mine was too!!!

Answer (score 8):

## Python (75)

```
r=range(1,10)
for i in r:print''.join('%sx%s=%-3s'%(j,i,i*j)for j in r[:i])
```

a little better golfed than the other two Python versions.

Comment: Use Python 3.6 with f-strings for -1 bytes: [TIO](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v8i2KDEvPVXDUMfQQJMrLb9IIVMhM0@hyKqgKDOvRENdXS8rPzNPI029Oqu2ojqz1rY6UyvLysa4Vh2kNgusNtoqM1ZT8/9/AA)

Answer (score 6):

## C++, <s>106</s> 98 bytes

I used two loops and a few tricks.

```
#import <cstdio>
main(){for(int i,j;i++-9;j=0)while(j++-i)printf("%dx%d=%d%c",j,i,i*j,j<i?32:10);}
```

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! Nice first post!

Comment: `#import <stdio.h>
main(){for(int i=0,j;i++-9;j=0)while(j++-i)printf("%dx%d=%d%s",j,i,i*j,j<i?"\n":" ";}` is 3 bytes shorter.

Comment: Do you need a space between `#import` and `<cstdio>`?

Comment: @Zacharý no that space is not needed

Answer (score 5):

## J: <strike>57</strike> 51 characters

```
([:;"2*\#"2(":@],'x',":@[,'=',":@*,' '"_)"0/~)>:i.9
```

No loops.

Comment: Conjunctions (and adverbs) have higher precedence than verbs so you can remove 3 pairs of brackets. `([:;"2*\#"2(":@],'x',":@[,'=',":@*,' '"_)"0/~)>:i.9`

Comment: @randomra Good call.  Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 4):

## Ruby: <s>60</s> 59 characters

```ruby
1.upto(9){|i|puts (1..i).map{|j|"%dx%d=%-3d"%[j,i,i*j]}*""}
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.2$ ruby -e '1.upto(9){|i|puts (1..i).map{|j|"%dx%d=%-3d"%[j,i,i*j]}*""}'
1x1=1 
1x2=2  2x2=4 
1x3=3  2x3=6  3x3=9 
1x4=4  2x4=8  3x4=12 4x4=16
1x5=5  2x5=10 3x5=15 4x5=20 5x5=25
1x6=6  2x6=12 3x6=18 4x6=24 5x6=30 6x6=36
1x7=7  2x7=14 3x7=21 4x7=28 5x7=35 6x7=42 7x7=49
1x8=8  2x8=16 3x8=24 4x8=32 5x8=40 6x8=48 7x8=56 8x8=64
1x9=9  2x9=18 3x9=27 4x9=36 5x9=45 6x9=54 7x9=63 8x9=72 9x9=81
```

Comment: Could save one character by changing the initial `(1..9).map{` into `1.upto(9){`!

Comment: There are trailing spaces (first 3 lines). The original table doesn't have them. I'm not sure if that makes a difference, though...

Comment: @WolframH, all solutions I checked either have trailing spaces or not reproduce the exact formatting.

Answer (score 4):

## D, 75 chars

```
foreach(i,1..10){foreach(j,1..i+1){writef("%dx%d=%d ",i,j,i*j);}writeln();}
```

you just said code not function or full program

Comment: By default, snippets are not allowed; a function or full program is required.

Comment: @quartata This answer predates our defaults by a year and a half.

Comment: @Dennis Oh, I didn't realize the no snippets allowed rule was that new. Sorry.

Comment: Would this work? `foreach(i,1..10){foreach(j,1..i+1)writef("%dx%d=%d ",i,j,i*j);writeln;}`

Answer (score 4):

### APL (37)

```
∆∘.{⊃(⍺≥⍵)/,/(⍕⍺)'×'(⍕⍵)'=',⍕⍺×⍵}∆←⍳9
```

And it's not even just two for-loops. In APL, the following construct:

```
x ∘.F y
```

where `x` and `y` are lists, and `F` is a function, applies `F` to each pair of items in `x` and `y` and gives you a matrix.

So: `∆∘.×∆←⍳9` gets you a multiplication table from 1 to 9. The above function generates the required string for each pair, i.e. `(⍕⍺)`, string representation of the first number, followed by `×`, followed by `(⍕⍵)`, string representation of the second number, followed by `=`, followed by `⍕⍺×⍵`, as long as `⍺≥⍵`.

Answer (score 4):

## Perl, 54 Characters

```
printf"%dx$?=%-3d"x$?.$/,map{$_,$_*$?}1..$?while$?++<9
```

Answer (score 4):

### APL (Dyalog), 28

```
↑{⍵{⍕⍵,'×',⍺,'=',⍺×⍵}¨⍳⍵}¨⍳9
```

Analogous to a double loop in other languages

`{⍵{...}¨⍳⍵}¨⍳9` sets up the double loop
`⍕⍵,'×',⍺,'=',⍺×⍵` creates the string for each pair
`↑` Convert array of array of strings to a matrix of stings

**Output**

```
1 × 1 = 1                                                                                                 
1 × 2 = 2  2 × 2 = 4                                                                                      
1 × 3 = 3  2 × 3 = 6   3 × 3 = 9                                                                          
1 × 4 = 4  2 × 4 = 8   3 × 4 = 12  4 × 4 = 16                                                             
1 × 5 = 5  2 × 5 = 10  3 × 5 = 15  4 × 5 = 20  5 × 5 = 25                                                 
1 × 6 = 6  2 × 6 = 12  3 × 6 = 18  4 × 6 = 24  5 × 6 = 30  6 × 6 = 36                                     
1 × 7 = 7  2 × 7 = 14  3 × 7 = 21  4 × 7 = 28  5 × 7 = 35  6 × 7 = 42  7 × 7 = 49                         
1 × 8 = 8  2 × 8 = 16  3 × 8 = 24  4 × 8 = 32  5 × 8 = 40  6 × 8 = 48  7 × 8 = 56  8 × 8 = 64             
1 × 9 = 9  2 × 9 = 18  3 × 9 = 27  4 × 9 = 36  5 × 9 = 45  6 × 9 = 54  7 × 9 = 63  8 × 9 = 72  9 × 9 = 81
```

Comment: you could remove some of the commas to the same effect: `↑{⍵{⍕⍵'×'⍺'=',⍺×⍵}¨⍳⍵}¨⍳9` or even make use of the new "key operator": `{⍕⍵'×'⍺'=',⍺×⍵}¨∘⍳⌸⍳9`

Answer (score 4):

### *Mathematica*, 45

Pretty boring, but I guess it serves as a syntax comparison:

```
Grid@Table[Row@{a, "x", b, "=", a b}, {a, 9}, {b, a}]
```

Comment: What, you're telling me there isn't a builtin for this?

Comment: @Aaron The function bloat of *Mathematica* doesn't extent *that* far yet, thankfully.

Answer (score 3):

### VBScript (133); without loops.

```
g=""
sub m(x,y)
    g=x&"x"&y&"="&x*y&vbTab&g
    if x>1 then 
        m x-1,y
    elseif y>1 then 
        g=vbLf&g 
        m y-1,y-1
    end if
end sub
m 9,9
wscript.echo g
```

On request of the challenger: no loops. This code uses recursive subroutine calls.

Answer (score 3):

## Maple, 64

```
seq(printf(seq(printf("%ax%a=%a ",j,i,i*j),j=1..i),"\n"),i=1..9)
```

Answer (score 3):

## x86_64 machine code (linux), <s>175</s> <s>99</s> 76 bytes

```
0000000000400080 <_start>:
  400080:   66 bf 09 00             mov    $0x9,%di

0000000000400084 <_table.L2>:
  400084:   6a 0a                   pushq  $0xa
  400086:   89 fe                   mov    %edi,%esi

0000000000400088 <_table.L3>:
  400088:   89 f0                   mov    %esi,%eax
  40008a:   f7 e7                   mul    %edi

000000000040008c <_printInteger>:
  40008c:   6a 20                   pushq  $0x20
  40008e:   3c 0a                   cmp    $0xa,%al
  400090:   7d 02                   jge    400094 <_printInteger.L1>
  400092:   6a 20                   pushq  $0x20

0000000000400094 <_printInteger.L1>:
  400094:   66 31 d2                xor    %dx,%dx
  400097:   b3 0a                   mov    $0xa,%bl
  400099:   66 f7 f3                div    %bx
  40009c:   83 c2 30                add    $0x30,%edx
  40009f:   52                      push   %rdx
  4000a0:   66 85 c0                test   %ax,%ax
  4000a3:   75 ef                   jne    400094 <_printInteger.L1>
  4000a5:   6a 3d                   pushq  $0x3d
  4000a7:   66 57                   push   %di
  4000a9:   80 04 24 30             addb   $0x30,(%rsp)
  4000ad:   6a 78                   pushq  $0x78
  4000af:   66 56                   push   %si
  4000b1:   80 04 24 30             addb   $0x30,(%rsp)
  4000b5:   ff ce                   dec    %esi
  4000b7:   75 cf                   jne    400088 <_table.L3>
  4000b9:   ff cf                   dec    %edi
  4000bb:   75 c7                   jne    400084 <_table.L2>

00000000004000bd <_printChars>:
  4000bd:   66 ba 00 08             mov    $0x800,%dx
  4000c1:   b0 01                   mov    $0x1,%al
  4000c3:   66 bf 01 00             mov    $0x1,%di
  4000c7:   48 89 e6                mov    %rsp,%rsi
  4000ca:   0f 05                   syscall
```

<s>This is a dump of the binary file, and all of this is 175 bytes. It basically does the same two loops that all the answers do, but printing to the console is a bit harder and basically requires pushing the characters to print onto the stack in reverse, and then making a (linux specific) syscall to actually put those chars into stdout.</s>

I've now optimized this so that only 1 write operation is performed (faster!) and has magic numbers (wow!) and by pushing the entire result onto the stack backwards before making the syscall. I also took out the exit routine because who needs proper exit code?

Here's a link to my [first](https://bitbucket.org/daveyhughes/ppcg/raw/8d730dafacaf6492673e3d348d2003e1485b8697/asm/mult_table.asm) and [second](https://bitbucket.org/daveyhughes/ppcg/raw/8d730dafacaf6492673e3d348d2003e1485b8697/asm/mult_table2.asm) attempts, in their original nasm syntax.

I welcome anyone who has any other suggestions on how it can be improved. I can also explain the logic in more detail if anyone is curious.

<s>(Also, it doesn't print the extra spaces to make all the columns aligned, but if that's required I can put the logic in at the cost of a few more bytes).</s>

EDIT: Now prints extra spaces and is golfed down even more! It's doing some pretty crazy stuff with the registers, and is probably unstable if this program were to be expanded.

Comment: PPCG requires full programs or functions. Snippets are implicitly disallowed (i.e. you can use them only if the OP has explicitly allowed them.)

Comment: Oh, my bad. I forgot OP hadn't specified that.

Answer (score 3):

### Javascript, 190 bytes

Late to the party, but I was piqued by @jdstankosky 's comment and decided to take a different approach. Here's a Javascript entry that mauls a template and evals itself along the way.

```
t="a*b=c ";u="";r=u;for(i=1;i<10;i++){a=0;u=u+t;r+=u.split(' ').map(x=>x.replace('a',++a).replace('b',i)).map(x=>x.replace('*','x').replace('c',eval(x.substr(0,3)))).join(' ')+'\n'}alert(r);
```

Un-golfed version (slightly older version in which a function returns the table instead of a script alerting it, but the same principles apply):

```
function f()
{
    t="a*b=c "; // template for our multiplication table
    u="";r="";  // tmp- and return values
    for(i=1;i<10;i++)
    {
        a=0;    // is auto-incremented in MAP
        u=u+t;// extend the template once per iteration
        v=u.split(' '); // Smash the template to pieces
        w=v.map(x=>x.replace('a', ++a).replace('b', i)) // MAP replaces the A and B's with the correct numbers
        w=w.map(x=>x.replace('*', 'x').replace('c', eval(x.substring(0,3)))).join(' '); // second map evals that and replaces c with the answer, makes the asteriks into an X
        r=r+w+'\n'  // results get concatenated
    }
    return r;
}
```

Comment: I made that comment a looong time ago, haha. I'm actually glad to see this.

Answer (score 3):

## [Pascal (FPC)](https://www.freepascal.org/), <del>128 125</del> 138 bytes

One recursive procedure takes care of everything. Call with `m(9,9)`.

```
procedure m(i,j:int8);begin if i<1then Exit;if i=j then begin m(i-1,j-1);writeln;end;m(i-1,j);write(i,'x',j,'=',i*j,' ':2-i*j div 10);end;
```

Ungolfed:

```
procedure m(i, j: int8);
begin
  if i<1 then
    Exit;
  if i=j then
  begin
    m(i-1, j-1);
    writeln;
  end;
  m(i-1, j);
  write(i,'x',j,'=',i*j,' ':2-i*j div 10);
end;
```

The reason for the byte count going up: the output was not aligned correctly. It is fixed now.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYxBEsIgFEP3PcXfUZyPI65ssUsPUoHqZ1pkELW3R8SukrxJEsanHmcxBZ1ziA9tzStaWFpC15NPJ66u9kYeaAI6y3S3Hi4rJfXLg4MK/o2yERKdkFx9IiU7e2W9URveYPllK0OHbGBIu6LA@qMoDgy9QR54HeV62Sxthx1XTUH7/AU)

Answer (score 3):

## Fourier, <del>756</del> 632 bytes

Thanks @BetaDecay for 124 bytes!

```
1o120~Ea1o61a1o10~Na1oEa2o61a2o32~Saa2oEa2o61a4oNa1oEa3o61a3oSaa2oEa3o61a6oSaa3oEa3o61a9o^a1oEa4o61a4oSaa2oEa4o61a8oSaa3oEa4o61a12oSa4oEa4o61a16oNa1oEa5o61a5oSaa2oEa5o61aNoSa3oEa5o61a15oSa4oEa5o61a20oSa5oEa5o61a25oNa1oEa6o61a6oSaa2oEa6o61a12oSa3oEa6o61a18oSa4oEa6o61a24oSa5oEa6o61a30oSa6oEa6o61a36oNa1oEa7o61a7oSaa2oEa7o61a14oSa3oEa7o61a21oSa4oEa7o61a28oSa5oEa7o61a35oSa6oEa7o61a42oSa7oEa7o61a49oNa1oEa8o61a8oSaa2oEa8o61a16oSa3oEa8o61a24oSa4oEa8o61aSoa5oEa8o61a40oSa6oEa8o61a48oSa7oEa8o61a56oSa8oEa8o61a64oNa1oEa9o61a9oSaa2oEa9o61a18oSa3oEa9o61a27oSa4oEa9o61a36oSa5oEa9o61a45oSa6oEa9o61a54oSa7oEa9o61a63oSa8oEa9o61a72oSa9oEa9o61a81o
```

Comment: I managed to [golf 124 bytes off your program](https://goo.gl/EteG0a) by saving the number 120 as the variable E, the number 32 as S and 10 as N.

Answer (score 3):

## [ConTeXt](https://wiki.contextgarden.net/Main_Page), <s>67</s> 60 bytes

```tex
\let~\dorecurse\starttext~9{~#1{##1x#1=\luaexpr{#1*##1} }

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

## Coreutils/Bash: <strike>147</strike> <strike>136</strike> 135

```
for i in {1..9}; do
  yes $'\n' | head -n $[i-1] > $i
  paste -dx= <(yes $i) <(seq $i 9) <(seq $[i*i] $i $[9*i]) |head -n$[10-i] >> $i
done
paste {1..9}
```

Golfed, using explicit newline and, using deprecated head option (thanks manatwork):

```
for i in {1..9};do yes '
'|head -$[i-1]>$i;paste -dx= <(yes $i) <(seq $i 9) <(seq $[i*i] $i $[9*i])| head -$[10-i]>>$i;done;paste {1..9}
```

Output:

```
1x1=1                               
1x2=2   2x2=4                           
1x3=3   2x3=6   3x3=9                       
1x4=4   2x4=8   3x4=12  4x4=16                  
1x5=5   2x5=10  3x5=15  4x5=20  5x5=25              
1x6=6   2x6=12  3x6=18  4x6=24  5x6=30  6x6=36          
1x7=7   2x7=14  3x7=21  4x7=28  5x7=35  6x7=42  7x7=49      
1x8=8   2x8=16  3x8=24  4x8=32  5x8=40  6x8=48  7x8=56  8x8=64  
1x9=9   2x9=18  3x9=27  4x9=36  5x9=45  6x9=54  7x9=63  8x9=72  9x9=81
```

Comment: Spare 8 characters by replacing all `$(( ))` arithmetic evaluations with `$[ ]`; share 2 characters by replacing the `$'\n'` escaped newline character with a literal one (I mean, `yes '` in one line, then `'` in the following one); spare 2 characters by not using `head`'s `-n` option explicitly, just `-` and the number.

Comment: @manatwork: I didn't know about the `$[ ]` notation, good to know. Replacing `-n` by `-` is only one character less so it's 11 in total, thank you very much :).

Answer (score 2):

### vba 55

(immediate window)

```
for f=1 to 9:for j=1 to f:?f;"x";j;"=";f*j,:next:?:next
```

note - GWBasic only needs 2 extra characters:

```
1 for f=1 to 9:for j=1 to f:?f;"x";j;"=";f*j,:next:?:next
```

Answer (score 2):

### Tcl 98 chars

```
while {[incr a]<10} {set b 0;while {[incr b]<=$a} {puts -nonewline "$a×$b=[expr $a*$b] "};puts ""}
```

Answer (score 2):

### Javascript, 75

```
for(s="",a=b=1;a<10;b=a==b?(a++,alert(s),s="",1):b+1)s+=b+"x"+a+"="+a*b+" "
```

I wonder if something better than two (combined?) for loops is possible...

Comment: well, the only thing I am sure is that it is possible to get 75 on _separated_ loops ([my old comment](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/11305/print-this-multiplication-table#comment22336_11334))

Answer (score 2):

## Python 2, 72

```
i=1;exec"j=1;exec'print\"%sx%s=%-2s\"%(j,i,j*i),;j+=1;'*i;print;i+=1;"*9
```

Output:

```
1x1=1 
1x2=2  2x2=4 
1x3=3  2x3=6  3x3=9
1x4=4  2x4=8  3x4=12 4x4=16
1x5=5  2x5=10 3x5=15 4x5=20 5x5=25
1x6=6  2x6=12 3x6=18 4x6=24 5x6=30 6x6=36
1x7=7  2x7=14 3x7=21 4x7=28 5x7=35 6x7=42 7x7=49
1x8=8  2x8=16 3x8=24 4x8=32 5x8=40 6x8=48 7x8=56 8x8=64
1x9=9  2x9=18 3x9=27 4x9=36 5x9=45 6x9=54 7x9=63 8x9=72 9x9=81
```

Answer (score 2):

### LOLCODE, 202 bytes

```
IM IN YR o UPPIN YR b TIL BOTH SAEM b AN 10
c R ""
IM IN YR i UPPIN YR a TIL BOTH SAEM a AN SUM OF b AN 1
c R SMOOSH c SMOOSH a "x" b "=" PRODUKT OF a AN b " " MKAY
IM OUTTA YR i
VISIBLE c
IM OUTTA YR o
```

Ungolfed:

```
HAI 1.3 BTW Unnecessary in current implementations
IM IN YR outer UPPIN YR multiplicand TIL BOTH SAEM multiplicand AN 10
    I HAS A output ITZ ""
    IM IN YR inner UPPIN YR multiplier TIL BOTH SAEM multiplier AN SUM OF multiplicand AN 1
        output R SMOOSH output AN SMOOSH multiplier AN "x" AN multiplicand AN "=" AN PRODUCKT OF multiplicand AN multiplier AN " " MKAY MKAY BTW AN is optional to separate arguments, a linebreak is an implicit MKAY.
    IM OUTTA YR inner
    VISIBLE output
IM OUTTA YR outer
KTHXBYE BTW Unnecessary in current implementations
```

Pythonated for non-leetspeakers:

```
for multiplicand in range(1, 10):
    output = ""
    for multiplier in range(1, multiplicand + 1):
        output = output + (multiplier + "x" + multiplicand + "=" + str(multiplicand * multiplier) + " ")
    print(output)
```

Comment: As someone who's also used LOLCODE in a code challenge submission, have my upvote! LOVE this lang

Answer (score 2):

## JAVA, <s>103 94 92</s> 90 bytes

Using JShell from Java 9 SDK allows me to save large amount of space

```
for(int i=0,j;i++<9;)for(j=1;j<=i;)System.out.print(i+"*"+j+"="+i*j+"\t"+(j++<i?"":"\n"))
```

Following  Kevin's suggestion I reduced solution by 2 bytes.

Thanks to cliffroot, I was able to reduce it by another 1 byte

Comment: You can save a few bytes by removing the `int ` from the second for-loop, and add `,j` to the first. So like this: `for(int i=0,j;++i<=9;)for(j=1;j<=i;)System.out.print(i+"*"+j+"="+i*j+"\t"+(j++<i?"":"\n"));`

Comment: It seems like you can replace `++i<=9` with `i++<9`

Answer (score 2):

**c#, 142 bytes**

```
Enumerable.Range(1,9).ToList().ForEach(i =>Enumerable.Range(1,i).ToList().ForEach(j=>Console.Write("{0}x{1}={2}{3}",j,i,j*i,j==i?"\n":"\t")));
```

And not a for in sight...

Comment: `ForEach` "not a for in sight" well... xD

Answer (score 2):

### Pyke, <s>17</s> 16 bytes (noncompeting)

Pyke was created after this question was asked

```
TFjSF\xj\=ij*s(P
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=TFjSF%5Cxj%5C%3Dij%2as%28P&warnings=0)

```
TFj           (  - for j in range(10):
   SF         (  -     for i in range(1,j+1):
     \xj\=ij*s   -         sum(i,"x",j,"=",i*j)
               P - pretty_print(^)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 50 bytes

```
1v
 1
?\::n"x"o{::n"="o}*n" "o1+:{:})
 \~1+:a=?;ao
```

You can try it on the [online interpreter](https://fishlanguage.com/playground).

Note that there is trailing spaces on each lines, which might make it incorrect (OP hasn't stated on this point as of this answer).

Answer (score 2):

## [///](https://esolangs.org/wiki////), 268 bytes

```
/_/\/\///x/×_N/x9=_E/x8=_V/x7=_S/x6=_F/x5=_R/x4=_O/
1_t/  2_h/ 3/1x1=1Ox2=2tx2=4Ox3=3tx3=6 hx3=9OR4tR8 hR12 4R16OF5tF10hF15 4F20 5F25OS6tS12hS18 4S24 5S30 6S36OV7tV14hV21 4V28 5V35 6V42 7V49OE8tE16hE24 4E32 5E40 6E48 7E56 8E64ON9tN18hN27 4N36 5N45 6N54 7N63 8N72 9N81
```

Answer (score 2):

## Excel, 57 bytes

Requires Excel 365 / 2019 version 2007 or newer

An excel worksheet function that defines the contextual arrays `c` and `r` then outputs an `9x9` array containg the output.

```
=Let(c,Column(A:I),r,Row(1:9),If(c>r,"",r&"x"&c&"="&r*c))
```

## Excel VBA Version, 64 Bytes

Anonymous VBE Immediate window function that takes no input and outputs to range `[A1:I9]` on the `ActiveSheet` object

```vb
[1:9]="=Let(c,Column(),r,Row(),If(c>r,"""",r&""x""&c&""=""&r*c))
```

#### Output

[image]

Comment: If you put `=LET(c,COLUMN(A:I),r,ROW(1:9),IF(c>r,"",r&"x"&c&"="&r*c))` into a cell, it is only 57 bytes.

Comment: @Axuary, thanks - for some reason I was thinking that I already had an Excel answer to this one, but I guess I didn't I've modified my response to show this approach being used both with and without VBA

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 23 bytes

```
9õÈõ_[X'×Z'=X*Z]¬ú6Ã¸Ã·
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=OfXI9V9bWCfXWic9WCpaXaz6NsO4w7c=&input=)

---

### Explanation

```
9õ                          :Range [1,9]
  È                  Ã      :Pass each integer X through a function
   õ                        :  Range [1,X]
    _              Ã        :  Pass each integer Z through a function
     [X'×Z'=X*Z]            :    Array [X,"×",Z,"=",X*Z]
                ¬           :    Join to a string
                 ú6         :    Pad end with spaces to length 6
                    ¸       :  Join with spaces
                      ·     :Join with newlines
```

Answer (score 2):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), <s>54</s> 52 bytes

```powershell
1..9|%{''+(1..($l=$_)|%{"$_`×$l={0,-2}"-f($_*$l)})}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/31BPz7JGtVpdXVsDyNRQybFVidcECiipxCccng7kVhvo6BrVKummaajEa6nkaNZq1v7/DwA)

Answer (score 1):

**Perl:  <strike>65</strike> , 62 characters**

```
map{map{printf"%dx%d=%2d ",$_,$i,$_*$i}1..($i=$_);print$/}1..9
```

Comment: Spare 2 characters by removing the `printf`'s parenthesis; spare 1 character by moving the assignment of $i into the range expression: `map{map{printf"%dx%d=%2d ",$_,$i,$_*$i}1..($i=$_);print$/}1..9`.

Comment: @manatwork: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

### Javascript: 82 characters

```
o="";for(a=1;a<10;a++){for(b=1;b<=a;b++){o+=a+"x"+b+"="+(a*b)+" "}o+="\n"}alert(o)
```

Comment: your code can be shortened to 75 like this `for(i=0,s="";9>i++;){for(j=0;j++<i;)s+=j+"x"+i+"="+j*i+" ";s+="\n"}alert(s)`, however the double spaces thing on 2 digits is not respected, I was about to submit that one but using `+(9<i*j?" ":"  ")` instead of just `+" "` **edit:** on the ternary the double spaces disappeared, but they are on the second param

Comment: I will be picky but `4x4` is not directly under `5x4` like in task.

Answer (score 1):

### Python: 87

I'm eyeballing the solutions others have posted and most of them don't appear to get the spacing correct.

```
for i in range(1,10):print''.join(('%s×%s=%s'%(j,i,i*j)).ljust(7)for j in range(1,i+1))
```

Comment: You have trailing spaces, does that count? ;-)

Answer (score 1):

### Python (79)

or (**77**) if I use `range(10)` except that produces an empty line at the start

```
for i in range(1,10):print' '.join('%dx%d=%-2d'%(j,i,j*i)for j in range(1,i+1))
```

---

```
1x1=1 
1x2=2  2x2=4 
1x3=3  2x3=6  3x3=9 
1x4=4  2x4=8  3x4=12 4x4=16
1x5=5  2x5=10 3x5=15 4x5=20 5x5=25
1x6=6  2x6=12 3x6=18 4x6=24 5x6=30 6x6=36
1x7=7  2x7=14 3x7=21 4x7=28 5x7=35 6x7=42 7x7=49
1x8=8  2x8=16 3x8=24 4x8=32 5x8=40 6x8=48 7x8=56 8x8=64
1x9=9  2x9=18 3x9=27 4x9=36 5x9=45 6x9=54 7x9=63 8x9=72 9x9=81
```

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby: <s>79</s> 77 characters (without loops)

```ruby
m=->i,j{"%dx%d=%-3d"%[i,j,i*j]+(i<j ?m[i+1,j]:j<9?$/+m[1,j+1]:$/)};$><<m[1,1]
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.2$ ruby -e 'm=->i,j{"%dx%d=%-3d"%[i,j,i*j]+(i<j ?m[i+1,j]:j<9?$/+m[1,j+1]:$/)};$><<m[1,1]' 
1x1=1  
1x2=2  2x2=4  
1x3=3  2x3=6  3x3=9  
1x4=4  2x4=8  3x4=12 4x4=16 
1x5=5  2x5=10 3x5=15 4x5=20 5x5=25 
1x6=6  2x6=12 3x6=18 4x6=24 5x6=30 6x6=36 
1x7=7  2x7=14 3x7=21 4x7=28 5x7=35 6x7=42 7x7=49 
1x8=8  2x8=16 3x8=24 4x8=32 5x8=40 6x8=48 7x8=56 8x8=64 
1x9=9  2x9=18 3x9=27 4x9=36 5x9=45 6x9=54 7x9=63 8x9=72 9x9=81
```

Answer (score 1):

**C++, 126 characters**

I took the expected approach.

```
#include <iostream>
int main(){for(int i=1,j;i<10;i++){for(j=1;j<=i;j++)std::cout<<i<<"x"<<j<<"="<<i*j<<" ";std::cout<<std::endl;}}
```

Answer (score 1):

## C, <s>86</s> <s>85</s> 84 bytes

```c
i;m(j){for(;i++^9;puts(""))for(j=0;j++^i;printf("%d×%d=%d %c",j,i,j*i,j*i>9?:32));}
```

Comment: j*v>9?:32 what does it mean?

Comment: j*v>9?:32  it seems as  j*v>9?0:32 but  j*v>9?32: here seems not compile...

Comment: [ideone](http://ideone.com/DQbySf) @RosLuP

Comment: Yes code as "a>b?9:;" I remember not compile in Ideone but code as "a>b?:9;" compile...

Answer (score 1):

## k (63 characters)

Prints the output to stdout.

```
-1@`/:" "/:'{7$x,"×",y,"=",z}.''$v,''(*).''v:(1+!:'t),''t:1+!9;
```

Example

```
k)-1@`/:" "/:'{7$x,"×",y,"=",z}.''$v,''(*).''v:(1+!:'t),''t:1+!9;
1×1=1 
1×2=2  2×2=4 
1×3=3  2×3=6  3×3=9 
1×4=4  2×4=8  3×4=12 4×4=16
1×5=5  2×5=10 3×5=15 4×5=20 5×5=25
1×6=6  2×6=12 3×6=18 4×6=24 5×6=30 6×6=36
1×7=7  2×7=14 3×7=21 4×7=28 5×7=35 6×7=42 7×7=49
1×8=8  2×8=16 3×8=24 4×8=32 5×8=40 6×8=48 7×8=56 8×8=64
1×9=9  2×9=18 3×9=27 4×9=36 5×9=45 6×9=54 7×9=63 8×9=72 9×9=81
```

Answer (score 1):

## VBA, 118 bytes

```
Sub M()
While B<9
B=1-B*(B<>A)
A=A-(B=1)
S=S &B &"x"&A &"="&A*B &IIf(A=B,vbLf,Space(2+(A*B>9)))
Wend
MsgBox S
End Sub
```

No for loops :-) and only one while loop.

And no If statements, so I could potentially one-line it and get the automatic "End Sub" for 8 fewer bytes if pushed; but I'm not that close to the leaderboard :-)

```
Sub M():While B<9:B=1-B*(B<>A):A=A-(B=1):S=S &B &"x"&A &"="&A*B &IIf(A=B,vbLf,Space(2+(A*B>9))):Wend:MsgBox S
```

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2, 91 characters

```
for k in[" ".join(["%ix%i=%i"%(j,i,j*i)for j in range(1,i+1)])for i in range(1,10)]:print k
```

Or, if each line as string like '1x2=2 2x2=4' is acceptable, this is 85 characters:

```
for k in[" ".join(["%ix%i=%i"%(j,i,j*i)for j in range(1,i+1)])for i in range(1,10)]:k
```

This one is slightly varied, resulting 93 characters:

```
print("\n".join([" ".join(["%ix%i=%i"%(j,i,j*i)for j in range(1,i+1)])for i in range(1,10)]))
```

Comment: This gives me syntax errors. Which version of python are you using?

Comment: Which one gave you a syntax error? All of them?

Python 2.7.11 (default, Jan 22 2016, 08:29:18)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.2 (clang-700.1.81)] on darwin

Comment: You're probably using Python3, in which case you should use print(k) instead of "print k" for the first solution.

Comment: @nukacolacolic You should probably mention in your post or in your heading that some or all of your code only works for Python 2 and not Python 3. It helps when other people want to check your answers.

Comment: You're right @Sherlock9 I'll edit the answer, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

### Convex, 27 bytes

```
9´{_´f{æ*'×@@'=\_s,¿)S*}N}%
```

[Try it online!](http://convex.tryitonline.net/#code=OcK0e1_CtGZ7w6YqJ8OXQEAnPVxfcyzCvylTKn1OfSU&input=)

Use the following version if only a single space is required between each equation:

### Convex, 21 bytes

```
9´{_´f{æ*'×@@'=\S}N}%
```

[Try it online!](http://convex.tryitonline.net/#code=OcK0e1_CtGZ7w6YqJ8OXQEAnPVxTfU59JQ&input=)

Answer (score 1):

### Javascript (using external library) (74 bytes)

```
n=>_.Range(1,9).WriteLine(v=>_.Range(1,v).Write(" ",x=>v+"x"+x+"="+(v*x)))
```

Link to lib: https://github.com/mvegh1/Enumerable

Code explanation: Create a range starting from 1, for 9 elements. For each integer in the range, write a line according to the predicate accepting the current value as the input param.

Each line in WriteLine will create a range from 1 to v, and write a space delimited string where each integer in the 1 to v sequence is mapped to the multiplication equation

[image]

Answer (score 1):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), 73 bytes

```
(1..10).forEach{(1..it).forEach{x->print("${x}x$it=${x*it} ")};println()}
```

Kotlin is the latest JVM language and I mainly wanted to try my hand at it.

You can try it on [their online interpreter](http://try.kotlinlang.org/).

Answer (score 1):

## Groovy, <s>65</s> 60 characters

```groovy
1.upto(9){x->1.upto(x){printf(x+"x$it=%-3d",x*it)}println()}
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.3$ groovy -e '1.upto(9){x->1.upto(x){printf(x+"x$it=%-3d",x*it)}println()}'
1x1=1  
2x1=2  2x2=4  
3x1=3  3x2=6  3x3=9  
4x1=4  4x2=8  4x3=12 4x4=16 
5x1=5  5x2=10 5x3=15 5x4=20 5x5=25 
6x1=6  6x2=12 6x3=18 6x4=24 6x5=30 6x6=36 
7x1=7  7x2=14 7x3=21 7x4=28 7x5=35 7x6=42 7x7=49 
8x1=8  8x2=16 8x3=24 8x4=32 8x5=40 8x6=48 8x7=56 8x8=64 
9x1=9  9x2=18 9x3=27 9x4=36 9x5=45 9x6=54 9x7=63 9x8=72 9x9=81
```

Answer (score 1):

## golflua, <s>54</s> 49 characters

```
~@i=1,9~@j=1,i I.w(S.q(i.."x%d=%-3d",j,i*j))$w()$
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.3$ golflua -e '~@i=1,9~@j=1,i I.w(S.q(i.."x%d=%-3d",j,i*j))$w()$'
1x1=1  
2x1=2  2x2=4  
3x1=3  3x2=6  3x3=9  
4x1=4  4x2=8  4x3=12 4x4=16 
5x1=5  5x2=10 5x3=15 5x4=20 5x5=25 
6x1=6  6x2=12 6x3=18 6x4=24 6x5=30 6x6=36 
7x1=7  7x2=14 7x3=21 7x4=28 7x5=35 7x6=42 7x7=49 
8x1=8  8x2=16 8x3=24 8x4=32 8x5=40 8x6=48 8x7=56 8x8=64 
9x1=9  9x2=18 9x3=27 9x4=36 9x5=45 9x6=54 9x7=63 9x8=72 9x9=81
```

Answer (score 1):

**C 79 bytes**

```
i=1,j=1;f(){printf("%dx%d=%d ",j,i,i*j);++i>j?++j,i=1,j<=9?puts(""),f():0:f();}
```

the main

```
main(){f();}
```

the table

```
1x1=1 
2x1=2 2x2=4 
3x1=3 3x2=6 3x3=9 
4x1=4 4x2=8 4x3=12 4x4=16 
5x1=5 5x2=10 5x3=15 5x4=20 5x5=25 
6x1=6 6x2=12 6x3=18 6x4=24 6x5=30 6x6=36 
7x1=7 7x2=14 7x3=21 7x4=28 7x5=35 7x6=42 7x7=49 
8x1=8 8x2=16 8x3=24 8x4=32 8x5=40 8x6=48 8x7=56 8x8=64 
9x1=9 9x2=18 9x3=27 9x4=36 9x5=45 9x6=54 9x7=63 9x8=72 9x9=81
```

Answer (score 1):

## Julia (236 Bytes, potentially 63) - Could use help.

```
A=[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9; 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9; 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9; 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9; 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9; 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9; 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9; 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9;1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
map(x->x>0?print(x,"x",x,"=",x*x,"\t"):println(),triu!(A'))
```

Someone put in the comments "Who's going to do anything but use 2 loops?"

**This guy is!**

I don't know how to instantiate matrices easily in Julia, anyone who could help me do the instantiation of the matrix better I will be grateful. I can only get it to make a 2D array, and triu doesn't work on that.

How it works:

- `A = [...]` creates a 9x9 matrix with 1-9 in each vector (someone please teach me to do this right without accidentally creating a 2D array... I want to learn this language better, but I'm confused on the typing differences and a lot of the documentation is pretty terse for matrices.
- `triu!(A')` takes the inverse of the upper triangle of the matrix.
- `map(x->x?0...:...,A)` mapping function that differentiates on x=0, printing a newline when needed.

Output:

```
1×1=1 
1×2=2  2×2=4 
1×3=3  2×3=6  3×3=9 
1×4=4  2×4=8  3×4=12 4×4=16
1×5=5  2×5=10 3×5=15 4×5=20 5×5=25
1×6=6  2×6=12 3×6=18 4×6=24 5×6=30 6×6=36
1×7=7  2×7=14 3×7=21 4×7=28 5×7=35 6×7=42 7×7=49
1×8=8  2×8=16 3×8=24 4×8=32 5×8=40 6×8=48 7×8=56 8×8=64
1×9=9  2×9=18 3×9=27 4×9=36 5×9=45 6×9=54 7×9=63 8×9=72 9×9=81
```

Comment: That was my comment! Lol, it's been some years.

Answer (score 1):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 73 bytes

```php
for(;$m++<9;print"
")for($n=0;$n++<$m;)printf("%d×%d=%-3d",$n,$m,$n*$m);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jXwAk0/KLNKxVcrW1bSytC4oy80qUuJQ0QYIqebYG1ip5QAmVXGtNsFSahpJqyuHpqim2qrrGKUo6Knk6KrlAUkslV9P6/38A)

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 25 bytes

Now fully conformant!

```
VS9jdm.[s[N\×d\=*Nd)\ 6SN
```

[Try it online!](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=VS9jdm.%5Bs%5BN%5C%C3%97d%5C%3D%2aNd%29%5C+6SN&debug=0)

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>22</s> 20 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
9LεLyâε'×ý'=yPðJ6∍]»
```

-2 bytes thanks to *@Grimmy*.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##AScA2P9vc2FiaWX//zlMzrVMecOizrUnw5fDvSc9eVDDsEo24oiNXcK7//8)

**Explanation:**

```python
9L                 # Push a list in the range [1,9]
  ε                # Map over each value `y`:
   L               #  Push a list in the range [1,y]
    yâ             #  Pair each value in this list with `y`
                   #   i.e. [1,2,3] and 3 → [[1,3],[2,3],[3,3]]
      ε            #  Map over each pair:
       '×ý        '#   Join the pair with "×" delimiter
          '=      '#   Push a "="
            yP     #   Push the pair again, and pop and push it's product
              ð    #   Push a space " "
               J   #   Join all three values on the stack together
                6∍ #   And then shorten the string to size 6
  ]                # Close both the maps
   »               # Join each inner list by spaces, and then each string by newlines
                   # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

Comment: `δ‚` => `â` for -1.

Comment: And [here’s 20](https://tio.run/##AScA2P9vc2FiaWX//zlMzrVMecOizrUnw5fDvSc9eVDDsEo24oiNXcK7//8) using `J` instead of `ý` + `«`.

Comment: @Grimmy Ah, of course. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

## [Burlesque](https://github.com/FMNSSun/Burlesque), 45 bytes

```
9roJcp:SOm{Jpdjimup"x="**j_+}{-]j-]==}gb)wduN
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyotykktLixN/f/fsijfK7nAKtg/t9qrICUrM7e0QKnCVklLKyteu7ZaNzZLN9bWtjY9SbM8pdTv/38A)

I'm almost positive there're multiple cuts that can be made here, but I just can't get them...

```
9ro     # Range [1,9]
J       # Duplicate
cp      # Cartesian product
:SO     # Filter for sorted-reversed
m{      # Map
 J      # Duplicate
 pd     # Product
 jimup  # Convert the two numbers into a string ({1 1} => "11")
 "x="** # Riffle in x=                          ("11""x=" => "1x1=")
 j_+    # Append the result
 }
 {
  -]j-] # Heads of both
  ==    # Are equal
 }gb    # Group by first digit being the same
 )wd    # Separate each internal list by spaces
 uN     # Separate main list by newline and prettify
```

Answer (score 1):

## Vyxal, <s>359</s> 20 bytes,  `-j` flag

[Try it online](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=j&code=9%C6%9B%C9%BEM%C6%9B%5C%C3%97j%5C%3D%2Bn%CE%A0%2B9%E2%86%B27%E1%BA%8E%3B%E2%88%91&inputs=&header=&footer=)

```
9ƛɾMƛ\×j\=+nΠ+9↲7Ẏ;∑
```

Finally, I'm done, and to round up LoTM, more forward-slashes. (Edit 1: the \s are gone)

Comment: [20 bytes](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=j&code=9%C6%9B%C9%BEM%C6%9B%5C%C3%97j%5C%3D%2Bn%CE%A0%2B9%E2%86%B27%E1%BA%8E%3B%E2%88%91&inputs=&header=&footer=)

Comment: @lyxal I had 39 :p

Comment: @Ausername honestly I just ported the 05AB1E answer

Answer (score 0):

## C#, 131:

```
Action<string> n=x=>Console.Write(" "+x);Action f=()=>{for(int i=1,x=1;i<10;i++){for(;x<=i;x++){n(x+"x"+i+"="+i*x);}n("\n");x=1;}};
```

Isn't the EXACT shape, but nearly there.

Comment: I'm not sure about the rules, but, isn't your code supposed to include all that is necessary to compile ?

Comment: I think I saw somewhere that putting an action is fine in C#.

Answer (score 0):

### Erlang escript 99

```
$ cat multi 

main(_)->[[[io:format("~bx~b=~-3b",[B,A,A*B])||B<-s(A)],io:nl()]||A<-s(9)].
s(X)->lists:seq(1,X).
```

and run

```
$ escript multi 
1x1=1  
1x2=2  2x2=4  
1x3=3  2x3=6  3x3=9  
1x4=4  2x4=8  3x4=12 4x4=16 
1x5=5  2x5=10 3x5=15 4x5=20 5x5=25 
1x6=6  2x6=12 3x6=18 4x6=24 5x6=30 6x6=36 
1x7=7  2x7=14 3x7=21 4x7=28 5x7=35 6x7=42 7x7=49 
1x8=8  2x8=16 3x8=24 4x8=32 5x8=40 6x8=48 7x8=56 8x8=64 
1x9=9  2x9=18 3x9=27 4x9=36 5x9=45 6x9=54 7x9=63 8x9=72 9x9=81
```

Answer (score 0):

## Javascript, ES6 65

```
for(i=0,r='';++i<10;r+='\n')for(e=0;e++<i;r+=i+'x'+e+'='+i*e+' ');
```

It was pretty fun to make!

Comment: Nice solution. However, your code does not output anything, and it does not include the required double spaces for alignment. With these added, your solution clocks in at 85 characters: `for(i=r="";10>++i;r+="\n")for(e=0;e++<i;r+=i+"x"+e+"="+i*e+(10>e*i?"  ":" "));alert(r)`

Answer (score 0):

**C 95 bytes**

```
i=1,j=1;f(){printf("%dx%d=%d %c",j,i,i*j,i!=2||j>4?:32);++i>j?++j,i=1,j<=9?puts(""),f():0:f();}
```

they want this table:

```
1x1=1 
2x1=2 2x2=4  
3x1=3 3x2=6  3x3=9 
4x1=4 4x2=8  4x3=12 4x4=16 
5x1=5 5x2=10 5x3=15 5x4=20 5x5=25 
6x1=6 6x2=12 6x3=18 6x4=24 6x5=30 6x6=36 
7x1=7 7x2=14 7x3=21 7x4=28 7x5=35 7x6=42 7x7=49 
8x1=8 8x2=16 8x3=24 8x4=32 8x5=40 8x6=48 8x7=56 8x8=64 
9x1=9 9x2=18 9x3=27 9x4=36 9x5=45 9x6=54 9x7=63 9x8=72 9x9=81
```

Answer (score 0):

### Racket 94 bytes

```
(for((n(range 1 10)))(for((i(range 1(add1 n))))(printf "~ax~a=~a  "i  n(* i n)))(displayln""))
```

Ungolfed:

```
(define (f)
  (for ((n (range 1 10)))
    (for ((i (range 1 (add1 n))))
      (printf "~ax~a=~a  " i  n (* i n)))
    (displayln ""))
  )
```

Testing:

```
(f)
```

Output:

```
1x1=1  
1x2=2  2x2=4  
1x3=3  2x3=6  3x3=9  
1x4=4  2x4=8  3x4=12  4x4=16  
1x5=5  2x5=10  3x5=15  4x5=20  5x5=25  
1x6=6  2x6=12  3x6=18  4x6=24  5x6=30  6x6=36  
1x7=7  2x7=14  3x7=21  4x7=28  5x7=35  6x7=42  7x7=49  
1x8=8  2x8=16  3x8=24  4x8=32  5x8=40  6x8=48  7x8=56  8x8=64  
1x9=9  2x9=18  3x9=27  4x9=36  5x9=45  6x9=54  7x9=63  8x9=72  9x9=81
```

Answer (score 0):

## tcl, 93

```
time {incr i;set j 0;while {[incr j]<=$i} {puts -nonewline $j\x$i=[expr $j*$i]\ };puts ""} 10
```

### [demo](http://rextester.com/YOB17904)

Comment: Alternative approach with same number of bytes: http://rextester.com/KPMD20731

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3.6](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>70</s> 68 bytes

```python
r=range(1,10)
for b in r:print(*[f"{a}x{b}={a*b:<2}"for a in r[:b]])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v8i2KDEvPVXDUMfQQJMrLb9IIUkhM0@hyKqgKDOvREMrOk2pOrG2ojqp1rY6USvJysaoVgmkKhGsKtoqKTZW8/9/AA)

Comment: I had not seen [Daniel's Answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/11409/69148) before submitting this, but credit to him for the original implementation of this idea.

Comment: [68 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v8i2KDEvPVXDUMfQQJMrLb9IIUkhM0@hyKqgKDOvREMrOk2pOrG2ojqp1rY6USvJysaoVgmkKhGsKtoqKTZW8/9/AA)

Answer (score 0):

## [///](https://esolangs.org/wiki////), 262 bytes

```
/;/=4//:/x\/\///-/ 6:,/=2//'/ 5:&/=1//%/ 4:#/ 3:"/
1:!/  2x/1x1&"2,!2;"3=3!3=6 #3=9"4;!4=8 #4&2%4&6"5=5!5&0#5&5%5,0'5,5"6=6!6&2#6&8%6,4'6=30-6=36"7=7!7&4#7,1%7,8'7=35-7;2 7x7;9"8=8!8&6#8,4%8=32'8;0-8;8 7x8=56 8x8=64"9=9!9&8#9,7%9=36'9;5-9=54 7x9=63 8x9=72 9x9=81
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DYy7bgUhDAX7fAUPAQ3Iy8PGBvlPbpMiUop02@zfb2jOFGc099/3/ftzvy9s0AGw4PnABwAKGFoZtAEkMLgiaAUIYMbyYPpy8FWXBWPaA/Wp0bVs23Zdu@1KxncVN7YdysaP2MKI5FDRYrw8RgyYr4QZHSlZis1T5EB5JNJ@lTPkpk474/Az1zAzp6kdy9zNzGducaxsOZLnPAJrb4n3VXjzuVmRDB/QcKJiJbKXPIOcbJKNRRTH8USpH090NiMHXN/3Hw)

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript, 70 characters

```js
for(s=i='';i++<9;s+='\n')for(j=0;j++<i;s+=j+'×'+i+'='+j*i+' ');alert(s)
```

Respecting alignment, 83 characters:

```js
for(s=i='';i++<9;s+='\n')for(j=0;j++<i;s+=j+'×'+i+'='+j*i+(j*i>9?' ':'  '));alert(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>84</s> 82 bytes

```hs
putStr$init$unlines[unwords[s i++'×':s j++'=':s(i*j)|i<-[1..j]]|j<-[1..9]]
s=show
```

-2 thanks to @Laikoni!

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfmfm5iZp2CrEPO/oLQkuKRIJTMvs0SlNC8nMy@1OLo0rzy/KKU4ulghU1tb/fB0datihSwgyxbI0MjUytKsybTRjTbU08uKja3JgjAtY2O5im2LM/LL////l5yWk5he/F83wjkgAAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 51 bytes

```perl
for$/(1..9){printf$_."x$/=%-3d",$_*$/for 1..$/;say}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/z8tv0hFX8NQT89Ss7qgKDOvJE0lXk@pQkXfVlXXOEVJRyVeS0UfqEgBqERF37o4sbL2//9/@QUlmfl5xf91fU31DAwNAA)

Answer (score 0):

## Excel VBA, 82 Bytes

Anonymous VBE immediate window function that takes no input and outputs to the VBE immediate window.

```vb
For y=1To 9:For x=1To 9:?IIf(x>y,"",Left(x &"x"&y &"=" &x*y &"  ",7));:Next:?:Next
```

Answer (score 0):

## [uBASIC](https://github.com/EtchedPixels/ubasic), 87 bytes

Anonymous function that takes no input and outputs to the console.

```
0ForY=1To9:ForX=1To9:z=x*y:Ifx<=yThen?x;"x";y;"=";z;" ";:Ifz<10Then?" ";
2NextX:?:NextY
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K01KLM5M/v/fwC2/KNLWMCTf0grIioCwqmwrtCqtPNMqbGwrQzJS8@wrrJUqlKwrrZVslayrrJUUlKyBslU2hgZgWRCfy8gvtaIkwsreCkRH/v8PAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Yabasic](http://www.yabasic.de), 101 bytes

Anonymous function that takes no input and prints a multiplication table to the console.

```vb
For y=1To 9
For x=1To 9
If(x<=y)Then
?Left$(Str$(x)+"x"+Str$(y)+"="+Str$(x*y)+"  ",7);
Fi
Next
?
Next
```

-3 bytes for the use of `Fi` over `EndIf`

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##q0xMSizOTP7/3y2/SKHS1jAkX8GSC8SugLI90zQqbGwrNUMyUvO47H1S00pUNIJLilQ0KjS1lSqUtMHsSiDbFsqu0ALxFBSUdMw1rbncMrn8UitKuOzB1P//AA)

Answer (score 0):

## [MY-BASIC](https://github.com/paladin-t/my_basic), 105 bytes

Anonymous function that takes no input and prints a multiplication table to the console.

`Str(...)` conversions are costly in this solution.

```vb
For Y=1 To 9
For X=1 To 9
If x<=y Then Print Left(Str(x)+"x"+Str(y)+"="+Str(x*y)+"  ",7)
Next
Print;
Next
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y63UTUoszkz@/98tv0gh0tZQISRfwZILxImAcTzTFCpsbCsVQjJS8xQCijLzShR8UtNKNIJLijQqNLWVKpS0QcxKINMWwqzQAnEUFJR0zDW5/FIrSrjA2qzB7P//AQ)

Answer (score 0):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 18 bytes, (17 chars, UTF-8)

```
9mc{b"`n×` =`*"mJ
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=9mc%7Bb%22%60n%C3%97%60+%3D%60*%22mJ&i=)

can't be compressed due to the unicode requirement. a 16 may be possible if I can find a way to compress it. [14 if using `x` is allowed.](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=dce6256591c1a7b013fa20362976&i=)