# Beginners 10x10 multiplication matrix

Tags: code-golf, kolmogorov-complexity, matrix

I was looking for a very easy task to look how short of a code can be produced on a beginners exercise.

The goal is to produce a simple table that looks like this common java/c# code is about 4 lines. So get your golfing-languages ready ;) Try to align the matrix in any way it is readable.

```
1 2 3    .. 10

2 4 6    .. 20

3 6 9    .. 30

. . .    .. .

10 20 30 .. 100
```

**EDIT:** The first answer below shows a propper alignment and solution

Comment: Can you provide an example of the desired output ? Or are you asking us to print the 10*10 matrix ?

Comment: yes, just the 10x10 matrix

Comment: Looks like a simplified version of [Print this Multiplication Table](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/11305/print-this-multiplication-table) and [Addition/Multiplication table generator](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/102197/addition-multiplication-table-generator). Not much challenging. Though occasionally the extremely simple questions' popularity is much higher. Unless closed. So I suggest to specify whether input will be provided, output must be text or formatted array is fine and whether the numbers need some kind of alignment.

Comment: Nice first challenge, but you would be wise to specify more clearly what exactly is required. E.g. may we return a list of ten lists? Don't use the word "Try"; either require it or say it isn't required. Etc.

Comment: If you do require alignment, which alignments are acceptable (left, right, all columns same width, single/multiple space separating columns, additional white space left and/or right, etc.)?

Comment: Please give one or more complete correct outputs. One might think that the output actually needs all the dots.

Comment: There's some grammatical problem in the sentence *The goal is to produce a simple table that looks like this common java/c# code is about 4 lines.*

Comment: Although not exactly duplicate, I think that this challenge is too similar to be interesting. It will only be closed if there are 5 people (or a gold badge holder) agree with that and nobody vote to reopen.

Comment: I don't think anybody has mentioned this yet, but welcome to PPCG!

Comment: [My answer before it was closed](https://tio.run/##K0nO@f@/JDM3VaG6OLVEIVMhOjMvuUihOJYLIlhQWlKsoJuXn5danpOZl6oQnZZflJtYoqBqnKKgkhkbo8AFVp@poFJcq2BowAVWr6QEYv//DwA)

Comment: @sergiol Annoying when a question gets closed just when you wanted to post an answer, isn't it? ;) [My answer in Java 10](https://tinyurl.com/y986srsp) and [my answer in 05AB1E](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f8/xM3PLsRHq6zSJd2kWPfwrlovnf//AQ). Both probably golfable (second one especially, I'm pretty new to 05AB1E).

Comment: Strange, it looks like the system somehow allowed me to post an answer when it was already closed! Nevertheless, I think it is not very nice to close a challenge, which is not technically an exact duplicate, when it has already accumulated a dozen of answers!

Comment: @KevinCruijssen: The maximum you can do about it is voting to reopen!

Comment: @KirillL. Can I suggest you voting to reopen?

Comment: @sergiol I already did...

Comment: I would vote to reopen but I have a gold badge, and I think this should be closed as unclear rather than a dupe.

Comment: @Giuseppe: For me the output sample made very clear what the question's poster want people to answer.

Answer (score 3):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 5 bytes

```
10:&*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/39DASk3r/38A)

```
10:    % Range: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
   &*  % Multiply the range by itself transposed, with broadcasting.
```

Outputs:

```
 1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10
 2   4   6   8  10  12  14  16  18  20
 3   6   9  12  15  18  21  24  27  30
 4   8  12  16  20  24  28  32  36  40
 5  10  15  20  25  30  35  40  45  50
 6  12  18  24  30  36  42  48  54  60
 7  14  21  28  35  42  49  56  63  70
 8  16  24  32  40  48  56  64  72  80
 9  18  27  36  45  54  63  72  81  90
10  20  30  40  50  60  70  80  90 100
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>48 45</s> 44 bytes

```ruby
1.upto(10){|x|puts"%4d"*10%[*x.step(100,x)]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/31CvtKAkX8PQQLO6pqKmoLSkWEFJ1SRFScvQQDVaq0KvuCS1AChroFOhGVv7/z8A)

-3 bytes thanks to manatwork then -1 thanks to Kirill L.

But I still think there must be a better way.

Comment: You not need the parenthesis around the `"%4d"*10`. And instead of `x*10` you can write just `100` then the placeholders in the format string will limit it to 10.

Comment: Now, when there are no parentheses, you don't need the space after `puts` either. As for a better way, it looks not so easy, e.g. an alternative approach gives still the same [44 bytes](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/XyPR1lBPz9BAUy83saC6JrOmoLSkWEnVJEVJy9BANREimlWTqZVVW/v/PwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 5 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jellylanguage/wiki/Code-page)

```
⁵×þ`G
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9R49bD0w/vS3D//x8A)

Prints the following text:

```
  1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10
  2   4   6   8  10  12  14  16  18  20
  3   6   9  12  15  18  21  24  27  30
  4   8  12  16  20  24  28  32  36  40
  5  10  15  20  25  30  35  40  45  50
  6  12  18  24  30  36  42  48  54  60
  7  14  21  28  35  42  49  56  63  70
  8  16  24  32  40  48  56  64  72  80
  9  18  27  36  45  54  63  72  81  90
 10  20  30  40  50  60  70  80  90 100
```

[Another 5-byter](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9R49bD0x81rQly//8fAA).

Comment: I'm so fascinated by those languages like Jelly, Brainfuck etc.... But I think I will never understand how to write code with these. Is there any 'tutorial' you can recommend?

Comment: For Jelly, I can recommend [its dedicated wiki](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jellylanguage/wiki). However, I suggest not accepting an answer this early, and in fact not accepting an answer at all because that doesn't encourage competition.

Answer (score 1):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), <s>18</s> 17 bytes

*1 byte saved thanks to [@StewieGriffin](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/31516/stewie-griffin)*

```matlab
disp((x=1:10)'*x)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/f8/JbO4QEOjwtbQytBAU12rQvP/fwA)

Or, as [@maxb](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/79994/maxb) points out: more readable, same length:

```matlab
x=1:10;disp(x'*x)
```

Comment: You could simply do `x=1:10;disp(x'*x)`. Same amount of bytes, and more readable.

Comment: @maxb Good idea; updated

Comment: _... and more readable_. That's almost a reason to not update the answer!

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 32 bytes

```r
write(format((x=1:10)%o%x),1,10)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/v7wosyRVIy2/KDexREOjwtbQytBAUzVftUJTx1AHyPz/HwA)

Comment: `write(format(1:10%o%1:10),1,10)` is shorter by one byte.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>64</s> 55 bytes

```python
i=1
exec"print'%4d'*10%tuple(range(i,11*i,i));i+=1;"*10
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P9PWkCu1IjVZqaAoM69EXdUkRV3L0EC1pLQgJ1WjKDEvPVUjU8fQUCtTJ1NT0zpT29bQWgmo4P9/AA)

Answer (score 0):

## Brainfuck, 1147 bytes

```
++[[<+++>-->----<]>]<<<<+.>..<+.>..<+.>..<+.>..<+.>..<+.>..<+.>..<+.>..<+.>..<--------.-.<<+.>>++.>..<++.>..<++.>..<++.>..<-------.-.>.<+.+.>.<-.+++.>.<---.+++++.>.<-----.+++++++.>.<------.--.<<.>>+++.>..<+++.>..<+++.>..<--------.+.>.<-.++++.>.<----.+++++++.>.<------.-.>.<+.++.>.<--.+++++.>.<----.---.<<.>>++++.>..<++++.>..<-------.+.>.<-.+++++.>.<----.--.>.<++.++.>.<--.++++++.>.<-----.-.>.<+.+++.>.<--.----.<<.>>+++++.>..<----.-.>.<+.++++.>.<---.--.>.<++.+++.>.<--.---.>.<+++.++.>.<-.----.>.<++++.+.>.<.-----.<<.>>++++++.>..<-----.+.>.<-.+++++++.>.<------.++.>.<-.---.>.<+++.+++.>.<--.--.>.<++.++++.>.<---.-.>.<++.------.<<.>>+++++++.>..<------.+++.>.<--.-.>.<+.++++++.>.<-----.++.>.<-.--.>.<++.+++++.>.<----.+.>.<.---.>.<++++.-------.<<.>>++++++++.>..<-------.+++++.>.<----.++.>.<-.-.>.<++.----.>.<++++.++++.>.<---.+.>.<.--.>.<+++.-----.>.<++++++.--------.<<.>>+++++++++.>..<--------.+++++++.>.<------.+++++.>.<----.+++.>.<--.+.>.<.-.>.<++.---.>.<++++.-----.>.<++++++.-------.>.<++++++++.---------.<<.>>+.-.>.<++.--.>.<+++.---.>.<++++.----.>.<+++++.-----.>.<++++++.------.>.<+++++++.-------.>.<++++++++.--------.>.<+++++++++.---------.>.<+.-..
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lZLdCsIwDIUfKCRPUPoiwwsVBBG8EHz@ubX5Oemq4BjrljXnO0lzeZ3vz9v7@lhXomUpRFSZt5u5nOqpbBdJFfn7yXoJS5OopH9nS@yte/4eLCxE/YXbq3/YJwS2zB3TKCacV7cT2p4@k1MjGst8YaA5JlcCGMxrsqMuFOZc28CJFQzY6U0CeUjvMWd2xaqWW0x4oEApqZDUItALRHDDSvjTGB942DtUiRrz6RsZIHCaVpNXyRPicFzDPCgADEfLcCwVZQ1g3BnggTxO5KS1w3TatHRcuMoVHsERATPmBoTAf5L0/C8A0P@JxCAaacfLIuv6AQ)

Thanks for [Jo King](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/76162/jo-king) for this solution !

### Old answer, 1164 bytes

```
+++++[>+++++[>++>+<<-]>>+>++<<<<-]>>-->++<+.>..<+.>..<+.>..<+.>..<+.>..<+.>..<+.>..<+.>..<+.>..<--------.-.>>.<<++.>..<++.>..<++.>..<++.>..<-------.-.>.<+.+.>.<-.+++.<.>---.+++++.<.>-----.+++++++.<.>------.--.>>.<<+++.>..<+++.>..<+++.>..<--------.+.>.<-.++++.>.<----.+++++++.>.<------.-.>.<+.++.>.<--.+++++.>.<----.---.>>.<<++++.>..<++++.>..<-------.+.>.<-.+++++.>.<----.--.>.<++.++.>.<--.++++++.>.<-----.-.>.<+.+++.>.<--.----.>>.<<+++++.>..<----.-.>.<+.++++.>.<---.--.>.<++.+++.>.<--.---.>.<+++.++.>.<-.----.>.<++++.+.>.<.-----.>>.<<++++++.>..<-----.+.>.<-.+++++++.>.<------.++.>.<-.---.>.<+++.+++.>.<--.--.>.<++.++++.>.<---.-.>.<++.------.>>.<<+++++++.>..<------.+++.>.<--.-.>.<+.++++++.>.<-----.++.>.<-.--.>.<++.+++++.>.<----.+.>.<.---.>.<++++.-------.>>.<<++++++++.>..<-------.+++++.>.<----.++.>.<-.-.>.<++.----.>.<++++.++++.>.<---.+.>.<.--.>.<+++.-----.>.<++++++.--------.>>.<<+++++++++.>..<--------.+++++++.>.<------.+++++.>.<----.+++.>.<--.+.>.<.-.>.<++.---.>.<++++.-----.>.<++++++.-------.>.<++++++++.---------.>>.<<+.-.>.<++.--.>.<+++.---.>.<++++.----.>.<+++++.-----.>.<++++++.------.>.<+++++++.-------.>.<++++++++.--------.>.<+++++++++.---------.>.<+.-..
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lZJbCgIxDEUXVJIVlGxE/FBBEMEPwfWPfeRxU0fBfkzbtLnnJtPz83R7XF@X@7aVPg7ik5Ra6SjSFm0110R9U1iY//6SDiYW4VqLHu5NcLWn92Albsa4svSD4VI3toVAy3SKCefZ3YT2XKGc2D03ojFO50xAc0yuBDCYN2RX3QAH1y5QYgUDblo6ykP6jDlTFdXyiDEtFCglFZJaBHqBCG5YCX8aow8e9g5VokZsUpABAn/TavIqaYe4/K7lPSgADEfLoCJDWQMIbwZ4Ia8vcqe1y@u01zJx4SpX@AmOCJgxNyAE/pOk538BgP5PJAaTER42eNve)

Oh god, this ended up way longer than I expected.

Here is how i did it :

```
Store values 48 ('0'), 32 (space) and 10 (new line)
+++++[>+++++[>++>+<<-]>>+>++<<<<-]>>-->++<
Print 1st line
+.>..<+.>..<+.>..<+.>..<+.>..<+.>..<+.>..<+.>..<+.>..<--------.-.>>.<<
Print 2nd line
++.>..<++.>..<++.>..<++.>..<-------.-.>.<+.+.>.<-.+++.<.>---.+++++.<.>-----.+++++++.<.>------.--.>>.<<
Etc.
+++.>..<+++.>..<+++.>..<--------.+.>.<-.++++.>.<----.+++++++.>.<------.-.>.<+.++.>.<--.+++++.>.<----.---.>>.<< Etc.
++++.>..<++++.>..<-------.+.>.<-.+++++.>.<----.--.>.<++.++.>.<--.++++++.>.<-----.-.>.<+.+++.>.<--.----.>>.<<
+++++.>..<----.-.>.<+.++++.>.<---.--.>.<++.+++.>.<--.---.>.<+++.++.>.<-.----.>.<++++.+.>.<.-----.>>.<<
++++++.>..<-----.+.>.<-.+++++++.>.<------.++.>.<-.---.>.<+++.+++.>.<--.--.>.<++.++++.>.<---.-.>.<++.------.>>.<<
+++++++.>..<------.+++.>.<--.-.>.<+.++++++.>.<-----.++.>.<-.--.>.<++.+++++.>.<----.+.>.<.---.>.<++++.-------.>>.<<
++++++++.>..<-------.+++++.>.<----.++.>.<-.-.>.<++.----.>.<++++.++++.>.<---.+.>.<.--.>.<+++.-----.>.<++++++.--------.>>.<<
+++++++++.>..<--------.+++++++.>.<------.+++++.>.<----.+++.>.<--.+.>.<.-.>.<++.---.>.<++++.-----.>.<++++++.-------.>.<++++++++.---------.>>.<<
+.-.>.<++.--.>.<+++.---.>.<++++.----.>.<+++++.-----.>.<++++++.------.>.<+++++++.-------.>.<++++++++.--------.>.<+++++++++.---------.>.<+.-..
```

Comment: [1147 bytes](https://tio.run/##lZLdCsIwDIUfKCRPUPoiwwsVBBG8EHz@ubX5Oemq4BjrljXnO0lzeZ3vz9v7@lhXomUpRFSZt5u5nOqpbBdJFfn7yXoJS5OopH9nS@yte/4eLCxE/YXbq3/YJwS2zB3TKCacV7cT2p4@k1MjGst8YaA5JlcCGMxrsqMuFOZc28CJFQzY6U0CeUjvMWd2xaqWW0x4oEApqZDUItALRHDDSvjTGB942DtUiRrz6RsZIHCaVpNXyRPicFzDPCgADEfLcCwVZQ1g3BnggTxO5KS1w3TatHRcuMoVHsERATPmBoTAf5L0/C8A0P@JxCAaacfLIuv6AQ). You were printing null bytes on the second line

Comment: There's got to be an algorithmic way of printing the numbers instead of kolmogorov'ing it

Answer (score 0):

## APL+WIN, 9 bytes

```
n∘.×n←⍳10
```

[Try it online! Courtesy of Dyalog Classic](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v@ob6qvz6O2CcZcjzra0/7nPeqYoXd4eh5Q5FHvZkOD/0DR/2kA)

Outer product multiplication of a vector of integers 1 to 10

Comment: on Dyalog you can get [7 bytes](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v@ob6qvz6O2CcZcjzra0/4/6pihd3j6o94Vj3o3GxoAue3/0wA)

Comment: @dzaima Unfortunately I am running an ancient version of APL+WIN which does not have the ⍨ operator ;(

Answer (score 0):

### Batch, 177 bytes

```
@echo off
for /l %%i in (1,1,10)do call:r %%i
exit/b
:r
set s=
for /l %%j in (1,1,10)do set/an=%1*%%j&call:c
echo %s%
:c
set n= %n%
if "%n:~3%"=="" goto c
set s=%s%%n%
```

Answer (score 0):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 9 bytes

```
*/~1+i.10
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/r/PzU5I19Lv85QO1PP0OD/fwA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 56 bytes

```
repeat n 10[repeat m 10[prin pad rejoin[n * m]4]print""]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0pN@R@UmhId@78otSA1sUQhT8HQIBrKzgWxC4oy8xQKElMUilKz8jPzovMUtBRyY01iQeIlSkqx//8DAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), <s>24</s> 23 bytes

```
A,:)_m*{:*"%4d"e%}%A/:n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85KzP3/31HHSjM@V6vaSktJ1SRFKVW1VtVR3yrv/38A)

Alternative without pretty printing:

```
A,:)_m*{:*}%A/:p
```

Answer (score 0):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 79 bytes

```javascript
(_=[...".........."])=>_.map((a,i)=>Array.from({length:10},(v,k)=>(k+1)*(i+1)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@18j3jZaT09PSQ8OlGI1be3i9XITCzQ0EnUygRzHoqLESr20ovxcjeqc1Lz0kgwrQ4NaHY0ynWygrEa2tqGmlkYmkNTU/J@cn1ecn5Oql5OfrpGmARQAAA)